# How to insert an element in order given an array?

Tags: c, arrays

Let us assume we have the following numbers in an array:  1, 3, 6, 15
If the user inputs a certain integer such as the number 5, than how could you have it inserted in the correct order in the above array so that you could print the following new array:
1, 3, 5, 6, 15. The array to be used is a variable length array and we are assuming that the user enters the numbers of the array in a sorted and non-decreasing order, so there is no need for sorting but just to insert an element (also entered by user) in the correct place. Below I have the code as to how far I got because I don't know what command to use to do the insertion of x into the array, and I am a newbie to C programming.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int insertion_array (int n, int ary[*]); 

int main (void)
{

    int n; // size    
    int x; // The element to be inserted in the array    
    int i, j;
    printf("Enter size of array: ");

    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the value of x: ");

    scanf("%d", &x);

    int ary[n];    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter number %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &ary[i]);
    } // for

    return 0;
} // main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could come up with a simple O(n) algorithm:

1. use binary search to find the place to insert, say position 5
2. shift all numbers after position 5 right
3. assign position 5 to the new integer

But there are O(lgn) algorithm for insertion, say AVL-tree, RB-tree and etc.  But are much more complicated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int binsearch(int *arr, int size, int key)
{
  int low = 0, high = size - 1;

  if (key > arr[high]) return size;

  while (high > low) {
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (arr[mid] > key) high = mid;
    else low = mid + 1;
  }

  return low;
}

int main()
{
  int size = 10;
  int *arr = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));

  int elem, len = 0;
  arr[len++] = 0;

  while (scanf("%d", &elem) != EOF) {

    int pos = binsearch(arr, len, elem);

    printf("%d\n", pos);

    int i;
    for (i = len-1; i >= pos; --i)
      arr[i+1] = arr[i];
    arr[pos] = elem;

    ++len;

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
      printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  free(arr);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3015922 Of course you can, and you must use some kind of loop. :)

Comment: @user3015922 Hi, the above is the basic flow, the general idea is shown, but the code is buggy, I'm working on it, if you like, you could debug on it :P

Comment: @user3015922 basically where you left of, I just wrapped your `scanf` stuff into a loop.

Comment: @user3015922 This is not working yet.  I was trying to scatch the idea.  I make the code work in a moment.  But I think following this simple idea, you could do what you want :)